# Mobile menu lockup at odd times

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, progressive-web-apps

I'm using jQuery Mobile (JQM) for an involved single page app. I'm using jQM's page feature, based on some old skool jQuery Mobile tutorials. We're having trouble with menu lockup.

The file jqm-demos.js and jqm-demos.css come from https://github.com/jquery/demos.jquerymobile.com/tree/master/1.3.2

[My demo program here:](https://zipzit.github.io/)

I've built a generic example, and I'm able to reproduce the fault.  The sequence to obtain menu lockup is to select the following menu choices in this order: (1->2->3->4->5->4-> lockup occurs here)

1. Login
2. Sales
3. Summary
4. Our Team
5. Reports
6. Our Team ---> From this point on, menu goes into lockup.

I'm not seeing root causes for this lockup issue. The lockup is very repeatable and is totally visible in Chrome dev tools on desktop browser.

Anybody understand what is causing the issue?
Anybody understand how to isolate the fault using Chrome Dev Tools?
Is there a fix?

Comment: Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the menu hangs at exactly the same spot if `data-ajax = true or false`.  When you click on Demo link above what do you see?

Comment: I see for instance the panels which are located inside each JQM page. Please look in Chrome dev tools at the many `div`s with class `ui-panel-dismiss` which will be created after each reload (menu click).

Comment: ... so the issue will be visible also after landing, for instance, on page #login, simply by clicking on #sales, #summary and finally #sales again. No need to go through all JQM pages.

Comment: I never before realized those elements were being created within the DOM.  but not sure that is a cause for the fail.  When you delete all of those elements from within DevTools, it doesn't change the lockup issue.